# How to import binary files into DolphinDB?

Tags: import, binary, variable-length-array, dolphindb

I have a binary file and I want to import it into DolphinDB. But the function [`readRecord!`](https://www.dolphindb.com/en/help/readRecord.html) does not support importing a table with a field in type of STRING:

```
f.readRecord!(tb)

ERROR MESSAGE:
Read only object or object without ownership can't be applied to mutable function readRecord!
```

I wonder if DolphinDB provides a function which supports importing a binary file containing a STRING type field?

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB does provide a function `loadRecord` to import a table from a binary file containing string fields. The string field must have fixed length. If the actual length of a string is shorter than the fixed length, it must be padded with ascii zero.